# Point of declaration of typedef/alias declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, language-lawyer

Is the following code valid?

```
struct B{ using X=int; };
struct D1:B{ using X=X; };   // (1)
struct D2:B{ typedef X X; }; // (2)
```

I would expect the point of declaration of D2::X to be between the two Xs in (2), but it seems both gcc 4.8 and clang 3.2 accept it.
Is this standard behavior ? References to the working draft/standard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a debate on whether `using X = X` should pick up the being defined `X` or the `X` that potentially already was in scope. To avoid "unknown types" and to make it similar to `typedef`, it was ruled that the being-defined `X` is not visible in its to-be-assigned type expression (**so rather than being similar to `int x = x`, it is similar to `typedef x x;`**).

Recall that `typedef` is just a normal declaration with the `typedef` keyword prepended. The first mentioning of `X` does not declare anything, it just says what type will be aliased. That's the major difference with `using X = X`  which *could* declare `X` earlier, if the committee decided that way.

Note however your code is has *effectively undefined behavior*, because it violates a rule that has no required diagnostic. 3.3.7p1b2

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

Answer (score 2):

In a `typedef` declaration, the final name is the one being declared, and that is the point of declaration. So the first `X` comes before the declaration of `D2::X` and therefore resolves to `B::X`.